# Python interpreted code optimisation

Tags: python, optimization, interpreter

Consider the following code snippet:

```
dict [name] = 0
dict [name] += 1
dict [name] += 1
```

Does the python interpreter automatically recognise the repeated references to the dictionary value and use a cached local reference instead?, somewhat akin to the aliasing optimisations of C/C++, becoming something like so:

```
value = dict [name]
value = 0
value += 1
value += 1
```

Obviously, it's not a big deal to do this manually but I'm curious if it's actually necessary. any insight, feedback, etc is appreciated.

Comment: That's the interpreter's implementation detail you should not worry about. Besides, this sort of micro-optimization is not all that meaningful on such a layer as Python's, stratosphere-high as it is. Any particular reason you are concerned about it?

Comment: Curiosity and a tendency to fret over every aspect of my code :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can run it through the disassembler to find out:

```
import dis

def test():
    name = 'test'
    tdict = {}
    tdict[name] = 0
    tdict[name] += 1
    tdict[name] += 1

dis.dis(test)
```

Running this we get:

```
 13           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('test')
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (name)

 14           6 BUILD_MAP                0
              9 STORE_FAST               1 (tdict)

 15          12 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
             15 LOAD_FAST                1 (tdict)
             18 LOAD_FAST                0 (name)
             21 STORE_SUBSCR        

 16          22 LOAD_FAST                1 (tdict)
             25 LOAD_FAST                0 (name)
             28 DUP_TOPX                 2
             31 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             32 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             35 INPLACE_ADD         
             36 ROT_THREE           
             37 STORE_SUBSCR        

 17          38 LOAD_FAST                1 (tdict)
             41 LOAD_FAST                0 (name)
             44 DUP_TOPX                 2
             47 BINARY_SUBSCR       
             48 LOAD_CONST               3 (1)
             51 INPLACE_ADD         
             52 ROT_THREE           
             53 STORE_SUBSCR        
             54 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             57 RETURN_VALUE
```

It looks like, in this case, that `LOAD_FAST` is loading up the values of `tdict` and `name` each time we try to access it to perform the increment, so the answer would appear to be no.

Comment: Impressive, I was not aware of the disassembler

Answer (score 9):

That type of optimization isn't possible simply by inspecting the code.  Your name `dict` could refer not to a native dictionary, but a user-defined object that implements `__setitem__`, and that method has to be called three times.  At runtime, a sophisticated implementation could note the actual value of the name, and make an optimization, but it can't be done before runtime without breaking some Python semantics.

Answer (score 1):

No, because that would not work, and you even demonstated that with your own code - it's actually not equivalent:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> name = 'x'
>>> a[name] = 0
>>> a[name] += 1
>>> a[name] += 1
>>> a[name] # ok no suprises so far
2
>>> a = {}
>>> a[name] = 0
>>> x = a[name] # x is now literally `0`, not some sort of reference to a[name]
>>> x
0
>>> x += 1
>>> x += 1
>>> a[name] # so this never changed
0
>>>
```

Python does not have C-ish "references". What you had in mind would work only for mutable types such as `list`. This is a very fundamental property of Python and you should probably forget everything C taught you about variables when programming Python.

Comment: Do you mean "C++ like references" instead of "C like references"?

Comment: I would say that on the contrary, Python does have "C++-like" references; what it doesn't have is variables of value type. Values are values, and variables refer to values. Well - they're like C++ references in that they're always valid and non-null, and "automatically dereferenced"; but like C++ pointers in that they can be re-seated and that assigning to them re-seats them; and unlike C++ entirely in that they're dynamically typed.

Answer (score 1):

Changing your two examples into something like this:

```
#v1.py
di = {}
name = "hallo"
di[name] = 0
for i in range(2000000):
    di[name] += 1
```

and

```
#v2.py
di = {}
name = "hallo"
di[name] = 0
value = di[name]
for i in range(2000000):
    value += 1
```

You can see in the following tests, that v2 is faster, but pypy is much faster :-)

```
$ time python2.7 v1.py
real    0m0.788s
user    0m0.700s
sys     0m0.080s

$ time python2.7 v2.py
real    0m0.586s
user    0m0.490s
sys     0m0.090s

$ time pypy v1.py
real    0m0.203s
user    0m0.210s
sys     0m0.000s

$ time pypy v2.py
real    0m0.117s
user    0m0.080s
sys     0m0.030s
```

SO: it's not good to optimize code for a single interpreter (I have not tested Jython for example...), but it's great when [someone](http://pypy.org/people.html) optimizes the interpreter...

Comment: I'm aware of that. But it's the same in the question: in v1, dict[name] is 2, in v2 value is 2. The question is whether both ways are treated (roughly) the same by the interpreter. And they are not, otherwise they would be (roughly) equally fast.

Comment: I had forgotten that was what the question did between reading the question and reading your answer :)